# React Rendering multiple times

Tags: reactjs, redux

My `App.js` folder switches to my `Login container` when url is `/login`, where I have used `useSelector` to return states from redux. My `Login Container`:

```
export default function LoginForm() {

console.log('Login Rendered')

const dispatch = useDispatch()


const redirect = useSelector(state => state.auth.redirect)
const loading = useSelector(state => state.auth.loginLoading)


const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState({ username: '', password: '' })

const onChangeHandler = e => setInputVal({
    ...inputVal,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
})


const submitLogin = e => { e.preventDefault(); dispatch(login(inputVal)); }

const responseGoogle = response => dispatch(googleLogin({ email: response.profileObj.email }))

if (redirect) return <Redirect exact to='/' />

return (
    <Login
        inputVal={inputVal}
    // onChangeHandler={onChangeHandler} 
    // submitLogin={submitLogin}
    //   loading={loading} 
    />
)}
```

My `Login Component` just has `UI elements` which acts upon `props` where I have used `React.memo` to avoid unnecessary renders. Everytime I switch `URLs`, `login container` is rendering 2 times and `login component` is rendered one time. When I reload the page, `container` is rendering six times. How can I minimize the times of render?
It is also causing my app to take more and more memory everytime. Is it because my component organisation is ineffective?

Comment: how about doing `const {redirect, loading} = useSelector(state => state.auth)` ?
also you  memoized the `Login` component and use `useCallback` for the handler that you are passing to it.

Comment: Thanks it helped component to re-render less using `useCallback`